# Исправление ссылок

Tags: php, ссылки

Сайт работает на основе БД MySQL, раньше был движок и ссылки в нем были примерно такие

```
.ru/index.php/option/content/task/view/id/301  
.ru/index.php?option=content&task=view&id=301
```

И все работало, не важно, как выглядела ссылка, открывался ИД = 301, но сейчас поменял движок, теперь у меня сайт открывает только ссылки такого вида

```
.ru/index.php?option=content&task=view&id=185
```

Но есть сайты, которые поставили ссылки на мой сайт вот так вот

```
.ru/index.php/option/content/task/view/id/301
```

Что делать? Как выходить из положения? Или как прописать так, что б и `.../content/task/...` такой метод тоже работал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать замену на нужный вид урла

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/option/content/task/view/id/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?option=content&task=view&id=$1 [L]
```

Вроде так

Comment: получилось )) но вот не задача, теперь если на странице была ссылка index.php?....... то теперь он ее видит как index.php/option/...../index.php?..... ((

Comment: А index.php нужен? Во фреймворке CodeIgniter так есть, можно убрать - красивее урл будет.
Тогда ссылки можно привести к виду

/option/content/task/view/id/123

Comment: Да, нужен (. просто еще такой момент что почему то при ссылке в таком виде index.php/option/ .... дизайн сайта не грузиться.

Comment: Указывайте везде в ссылках и адресах к изображениям и css-файлам не "index.php...", a "/index.php...". проблема с "index.php/option/...../index.php?" исчезнет и дизайн грузиться будет